# Change the value of a property using ngxs

Tags: angular, ngxs

I have nested objects and would like to change only the value of one property within a nested object.

I tried to patch, immer, but in all cases I do not understand why it is not possible.

It is sometimes reported that the property is read-only, sometimes the object is not extensible.

Using patch, I'm not able to because it requires all object properties to be entered.

And since the object has other objects and many other properties, I would like to just update one property.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong.

```
  @Action(SetPropertyValueAction)
  public setPropertyValueAction(ctx: StateContext<OneStateModel>, { propertyValue }: SetPropertyValueAction) {
    // Of course this does not work, but it is to show what I need to happen.
    const state = ctx.getState();
    const obj = state.obj;
    obj.object1.object2.object3.property1 = propertyValue;
    ctx.patchState({ obj });

    // I would like to do something like that, but I can't.
    ctx.patchState({
      obj: {
        object1: {
          object2: {
             property1: propertyValue
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

The problem is that the object has a complex structure and I can't report all of its properties.

```
obj: {
   prop1: number,
   prop2: number,
   prop3: number,
   object1: {
      prop1: number,
      prop2: number,
      object2: {
        prop1: number,
        prop2: number
      }
   },
}
```

Comment: with the caveat that I don't know ngxs just ngrx...if the objects have unique ids I recommend the entity pattern and completely flattening your store (normalizr is one tool). This let's you update state once in one place. If you need combined state you do this in your selectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When u use the store patter u never modify any object in the store. U need one new object with the changes. Use the spread operator `...` to make this more easy.

```
ctx.setState({
  ...state,
  obj: {
    ...state.obj,
    object1: {
      ...state.obj.object1,
      object2: {
        ...state.obj.object1.object2,
        object3: {
          ...state.obj.object1.object2.object3,
          property1: propertyValue,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, @ManuelPanizzo.

I tried using the way you mentioned, I need to enter all properties of the strongly typed object in this case.

I will keep trying, thanks.

Comment: After some trying and insisting, I finally got to the solution using spread operator.

I still don't know if it's the cleanest way, but it works.
In my case, after using spread operator I had to type it with "as MyObject"

Thank you for your help, @ManuelPanizzo.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this is the expected way to update a single nested property.

```
ctx.setState(patch({
  obj: patch({
    object1: patch({
      object2: patch({
        object3: patch({
          property1: propertyValue,
        }),
      }),
    }),
  }),
}));
```